# Run intellij plugin on Android Studio

Tags: intellij-plugin

I'm developing an intellij plugin supposed to be used in android studio. 
I've already setup the plugin development environment, but when I hit "Run" command it starts a new intellij instance with the plugin installed.

What I'm looking for is how to run the plugin directly on Android Studio, is that possibile? The only place where I think it can be configured is from "Run configurations" but I do not find anything useful there.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can specify the platform to run on in the `IntelliJ Platform Plugin SDK` settings, under `Platform Settings | SDKs` in the `Project Structure` settings. Point the `IntelliJ Platform Plugin SDK home path` to your Android Studio installation.

Another option is to create a new Plugin Run Configuration. In the Run Configuration it is possible to specify the JRE to run on. Click on the `...` button there and select an Android Studio installation directory (e.g. `/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents` on the Mac). This way it is possible to create a Run Configuration for all IntelliJ Platform IDEs you want to test your plugin on.

Comment: didn't worked, obviously all the references to plugin development name spaces like com.intellij.openapi.* are not present in android studio

Comment: Well it works for me. All API's used by the plugin have to be present in Android Studio or the plugin won't work. But I have edited my answer to add another solution which may work for you and is probably easier.

Comment: Configuring an Android Studio SDK is a better solution, because it forces you to rebuild your project and make sure you're not using classes that are not available in AS. `com.intellij.openapi.*` *is*  present in AS, it's built on top of the IntelliJ platform!